# How to declare a function with a parameter that has the same signature as the function?

Tags: c

How can I declare a function that takes a function pointer, to a function with the same signature as the function, as an argument?

In gcc, what does not work is

```
foo_t * f(bar_t const *, typeof(f) *);
```

or

```
typedef foo_t (* f_t)(bar_t const *, f_t);
f_t f;
```

I do not want to cast to `void *` and back if possible.

Comment: it sound like that signature would be infinitley recursive

Answer (score 2):

You can use a forward-declared struct to break the type recursion (this is roughly similar to a functor or callable object in C++)

```
struct Func;
typedef foo_t *(*FuncFunc)(bar_t const *b, struct Func *);

struct Func { FuncFunc callee; };
foo_t * f(bar_t const *b, struct Func *func) {
  Func nextfunc = { f };
  return func->callee(b, nextfunc); /* <-- infinite recursion */
}
```

Using void/cast and varargs are both hacks - the above at least preserves type information.